# Set value from parent through child method c++

Tags: c++

Situation:

- Bullet inherits from GameObject.
- GameObject has method 'GetCoords' and 'SetCoords'
- Bullet has method 'MoveObject'
- 'MoveObject' gets the coords from 'GetCoords' to set them in 'SetCoords'
- Coordinates do not change

**GameObject.h**

```
struct Coordinates {
    float xPos;
    float yPos;
};

//GameObject
class GameObject {
    public:
    GameObject() {};
    GameObject(unsigned int a_id, float a_xPos, float a_yPos, float a_speed, States a_state = State::Idle);
    ~GameObject();

    //Methods
    void MoveObject(float changeXPos, float changeYPos);
    void MoveObject(float changeYPos);

    Coordinates GetCoords() { return Coords; }

    void SetCoords(Coordinates a_Coords) { Coords = a_Coords; }

    private:
        Coordinates Coords;
};
```

**Bullet.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObject.h"

class Bullet : public GameObject {
public:
    Bullet(unsigned int a_Id, float a_xPos, float a_yPos, float a_speed, States a_state = State::Idle) : GameObject(a_Id, a_xPos, a_yPos, a_speed, a_state) {}

    void MoveObject(float changeYPos);
};
```

**Bullet.cpp**

```
#include "Bullet.h"

void Bullet::MoveObject(float changeYPos)
{
    Coordinates coords = GameObject::GetCoords();
    coords.yPos += changeYPos;
    this->SetCoords(coords);
}
```

I tried 'this->SetCoords();' and 'GameObject::GetCoords();' to no avail.

I just tried this:

```
void GameObject::MoveObject(float changeYPos)
{
    Coordinates coords = GetCoords();
    coords.yPos += changeYPos;
    SetCoords(coords);
}
```

**Main Game Class**

The point where MoveObject is getting called:

```
for each (auto bullet in bullets)
{
    Coordinates coords = bullet.GetCoords();
    std::cout << bullet.GetCoords().xPos << ", " << bullet.GetCoords().yPos << std::endl;
    bullet.MoveObject(.3f);
    if (bullet.GetCoords().yPos > m_iScreenHeight) { 
        bullets.erase(bullets.begin()); 
        DestroySprite(bullet.GetId()); 
        break; 
    }

    coords = bullet.GetCoords();
    std::cout << bullet.GetCoords().xPos << ", " << bullet.GetCoords().yPos << std::endl;
    MoveSprite(bullet.GetId(), bullet.GetCoords().xPos, bullet.GetCoords().yPos);

    CheckHitEnemy(bullet.GetCoords().xPos, bullet.GetCoords().yPos, bullet.GetId());
}
```

The second cout **does have** different coordinates.

The point where the bullets get created, this gets called when the spacebar is pressed:

```
Bullet bullet(CreateSprite("./images/bullet.jpg", 3, 20, true), xPos, yPos, 1);

MoveSprite(bullet.GetId(), bullet.GetCoords().xPos, bullet.GetCoords().yPos);

bullets.push_back(bullet);
```

Comment: I see no immediately obvious reason why simply `SetCoords(coords);` and `GetCoords();` would not work as they are both public members of the object.

Comment: Can you shrink down your class to a point only the needed functions are there and look if this is still the case? Also just a general tip: write you variables lower case and not starting with Uppercase. that confuses most people reading your code.

Comment: @Hayt Done that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code and watching `coords`?

Comment: @George I did, the 'coords' variable that gets passed into SetCoords has the right values. Then when the code gets to this code again (the next frame) the values are back to what they were.

Comment: Interesting, can you please show the code where you create your bullet object?

Comment: Cannot reproduce [Demo](https://ideone.com/KMSNXP).

Comment: Given that the values "reset", my guess would be that you're re-creating your bullet each frame.

Comment: Note that you create a lot of copies as in `Coordinates GetCoords()` which should be `const Coordinates& GetCoords() const`. I bet that you change a copy of the bullet you want to change.

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht You really need to show the code where you're creating your bullet object.

Comment: @George I added everything. The bullet gets created in a function that gets the current x and y coordinates of the player.

Comment: @Wouter Vanacht Hmmmm, my main guess would be that your `for each`  loop maybe get's a copy of your bullets vector. That would explain it and is almost certainly what is happening if the bullets retain their start positions. Make sure you're manipulating the original vector when setting values on it's contained objects.

Comment: Yep I just figured that out. I'm going to try some things. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Changing my for each loop to a for loop with the code changing from `bullet.MoveObject` to `bullets[i].MoveObject` did the trick!

Comment: Ok, so the objects we're being copied, you could if you wanted use `for each (auto& bullet : bullets)` and it should work, but hey at least it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you are missing the `virtual` keyword before your `MoveObject` declaration in the base class.

The way this is now, when you have a `GameObject`pointer/reference it will call `MoveObject` from `GameObject` and not from `Bullet`

So maybe change it to

```
virtual void MoveObject(float changeXPos, float changeYPos);
```

etc.

I am not sure if it fixes you problem, but later you can run into other problems with that. If you have c++11 available you should also look into the `override` keyword

Comment: How should I access the `SetCoords` and `GetCoords` functions then?
With `GameObject::Function()` or `this->Function()`?

Comment: They should be accessible by simply `SetCoords` and `GetCoords`. You should declare each function you want to override in a derived class declare `virtual` though in your base class.

Comment: But I don't have to override them right? They have a body in the GameObject class that would be the same for the Bullet class. I can't just access them without declaring them, as you said.

Comment: What is the error if you simply use `SetCoords`? `this->SetCoord` and `GameObject::SetCoords` will do all the same in your case. I think you have the origin of your problem wrong. It's not this call but something else.

Comment: And you really want to use `virtual` if you are working with inheritance.